# What's happening with search.cpan.org and how to install an redirector?

Tags: perl, cpan

### EDITED question

It last 2 weeks `search.cpan.org` was down many times. Yes i know here is a metacpan, but zilion of links from the net points to `search.cpan.org` so the metacpan isn't the "only" solution.

Want make a local redirector, by entering to my `/etc/hosts` something like:

```
search.cpan.org    127.0.0.1
```

and run an simple PSGI (or Apache) server on `localhost:80` what should done the redirects. So the requests for "search.cpan.org" would be processed at "localhost" with the script and it should return valid `302` responses and redirect to `metacpan.org`.

@Mpapec pointed to `mcpan.org` - what doing exactly for what i looking, so now enoudh redirect every request to "mcpan.org".

After edited my `/etc/hosts` as above, tried the next apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName search.cpan.org
        RedirectPermanent / http://search.mcpan.org/
</VirtualHost>
```

but doesn't work. Would be nice to get some help. Or an alternative, a simple `app.psgi` script would be nice too.

So, the questions are:

- how to configure local apache for redirects search.cpan.org -> search.mcpan.org
- or how to write a simple `app.psgi` for running it with `plackup -p 80` for the same function

and one offtopic question:

- know anyone something about the status and a future of `search.cpan.org`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because neither of the three sub-questions are on topic here. We're not the Internet's global support. Resource requests are off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the status of a website, not programming.

Comment: `Re: redirector` http://perlmaven.com/jumping-from-search-cpan-org-to-metacpan-org Wish there is http://perl.stackexchange.com/ for queestions like this.

Comment: according to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251169/offsite-web-based-tool-commonly-used-by-developers the question is not offtopic.

Comment: "where can download the original source code for the search.cpan.org?" - you can't; it's closed source. This is one of many reasons metacpan.org is the superior site.

Comment: Hm... seems here is some background "war" between _Perl institute_ (owner of cpan.org) and _Perl foundation_ (owner of metacpan.org). Not working search.cpan.org **hurts** perl, so if someone want stop search.cpan.org it should at least put to search.cpan.org an redirector what should redirect requests to the metacpan.org. The current status is really boring. BTW, here is already one reopen vote - voting to reopen too, (and reformulate the question) to: how to write a a simple PSGI cpan->metacpan redirector... ;)

Comment: There is no background war. The Perl Institute does not exist. I took that over a long time ago, then merged it with The Perl Foundation.  The cpan.org domain is different than a particular host. Elaine Ashton and Jarkko Hientenami control the domain records, but not every host. search.cpan.org is run by Graham Barr (by himself).

Comment: @briandfoy Thank you for explanation. Good to know. :) So, if "Graham Barr" doesn't want or can't run the "search.cpan.org", would be nice from him - installing the redirector. This and above is pure IMHO. Anyway, would be nice to get the "mcpan.org" redirector opensource :) - after it anybody can install it for yourself and "problem solved"...

Comment: search.cpan.org is back up as of now

Answer (score 4):

search.cpan.org is run by [Graham Barr](http://perlresume.org/GBARR). For questions about websites that he runs, you'll have to contact him.

The source code is not available. That's why MetaCPAN sprang up.

I wouldn't bother with a redirector. Maybe a Greasemonkey script, though :)

Answer (score 2):

I was an configuration error in my `apache`. The next works.

1.) edit /etc/hosts and add a line `IP.OF.YOUR.LOCAL.WEBSERVER search.cpan.org`, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1 search.cpan.org
```

2.) for apache (i have 2.4) into httpd.conf enter

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName search.cpan.org
        Redirect / http://search.mcpan.org/
</VirtualHost>
```

3.) Be sure than your apache listening on port 80 e.g. have a directive

```
Listen 80
```

With the above, every request to "search.cpan.org" get redirected to "search.mcpan.org" and the "mcpan" redirects it to "metacpan". It is suboptimal, would be nicer to have a set of rewrite rules what redirects directly into "metacpan", but works.